# jQuery tabs dont work when I follow link to the page in my rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tabs

I followed a tutorial located here:

http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery

to make tabs with css, html, and jQuery. It works fine, but if I go to a different page, then click a link in my navbar to go back to the page with the tabs, clicking the tabs does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) is the culprit here. Added to Rails to help speed up page load times, it messes up some jQuery things because it prevents the browser from recompiling the JS each time you visit a page.

Basically, the `jQuery(document).ready(function() {...});` section of your tabs code isn't being run when you revisit a page you've already been to.  Rails already ran the javascript the first time, so to speed things up, it didn't do it the second time. Unfortunately for you, you needed the javascript again!

Fortunately for you, jQuery was smart and has a nice event called `page:load` which works great!  Add in the following code:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
    // tab code goes here
});
```

And that should work!

**EDIT**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  tabs_init();
});

$( document ).on('page:load', function() {
  tabs_init();
});

function tabs_init() {
  jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href'); // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(400).siblings().hide(); // Change/remove current tab to active
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(400).siblings().hide();
 
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});`              is my current code, should i wrap all of that in what you gave me? Or should I replace the first line with what you gave me?

Comment: You're best extracting the code into a separate function, see my edit!